# How to set Access-Control-Allow-Origin for a ReactNative App

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

The app worked ok a few weeks ago but now gives

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at
  'https://api.yelp.com/v3/businesses/search?limit=50&term=black+lives&location=cambridge+MA' 
from origin 'http://localhost:19006' has been blocked by CORS policy:
  Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: 
    No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

For a **ReactNative Expo** application - i.e. no index.js or index.html, etc. how to fix and
where to put the code to fix it given my current application structure is:

[image]

api settings:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
export default axios.create({
  baseURL: 'https://api.yelp.com/v3/businesses',
  headers: {
    Authorization: 'Bearer ' + process.env.EXPO_YELP_API_KEY }
}
```

I use `...await yelp.get('/search', {...` in making the call

fyi I a running the web browser simulator to see the page

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is on the side of the API, not the front-end app.

I tried to execute the an Ajax request on that endpoint it looks like it does not include a `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header

[image]

If that header is present, it should typically look something like:

[image]

This example is from my API which allows all origins, where `null` is my origin because I executed this on my file system (not on a web server)

So in short, you need to configure the API to allow requests coming from `http://localhost:19006`